# Get ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME or ENOENT or ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME when use absolute path on Windows node js

Tags: node.js, windows, absolute-path

When I run my code on Linux it works fine. But on Windows with the same node js version(18.18.0) I get errors.

I use modern ES imports and my package.json has string `"type": "module"`.

I write discord bot and that is what I do:

```js
const rootDir = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const commandsPath = join(rootDir, 'src', 'commands');
console.log('BEFORE FILTER');
const commandFiles = readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

console.log('BEFORE LOOP');
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    console.log('BEFORE JOIN');
    const filePath = join(commandsPath, file);
    console.log('BEFORE AWAIT');
    const command = await import(filePath);
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    // etc...
```

So, if I run this code I get the logs `BEFORE FILTER`, `BEFORE LOOP`, `BEFORE JOIN`, `BEFORE AWAIT` and error

`Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'`

I tried to change `commandsPath` initialization:

```js
const commandsPath = join('file:', rootDir, 'src', 'commands');
```

Runs with the log `BEFORE FILTER` and *ENOENT* error with the **correct** path to commands directory

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'file:\C:\Users\Correct\Path\To\src\commands'`

If I try

```js
const commandsPath = fileURLToPath(join('file:', rootDir, 'src', 'commands'));
```

`BEFORE FILTER`, `BEFORE LOOP`, `BEFORE JOIN`, `BEFORE AWAIT` and the first example `ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME` error

And finally, if I try

```js
const commandsPath = fileURLToPath(join('file:', rootDir, 'src', 'commands'));
```

and

```js
const command = await import(fileURLToPath(filePath));
```

`BEFORE FILTER`, `BEFORE LOOP`, `BEFORE JOIN`, `BEFORE AWAIT` and `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL_SCHEME]: The URL must be of scheme file`

What should I do?